# Export React mixin in a separated file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mixins, reactjs-flux

I am trying to separate the SetIntervalMixin into a different file that the component class file. Maybe I am not fully understand how module.export works but... If I do like this:

```
module.exports = {
 componentWillMount: function() {
   this.intervals = [];
 },
 setInterval: function() {
   this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
 },
 componentWillUnmount: function() {
   this.intervals.map(clearInterval);
 }
};
```

inside a SetIntervalMixin.js, then it works fine using from the component:

```
var SetIntervalMixin = require('../util/mixins/SetIntervalMixin')
```

But if I write it like this:

```
var SetIntervalMixin = {

  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.intervals = [];
  },
  setInterval: function() {
    this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.intervals.map(clearInterval);
  }
};

module.export = SetIntervalMixin;
```

It doesn't work (undefined when trying to call setInterval()). I think something is missing after:

```
SetIntervalMixin = ...
```

Like when you define a component, you use:

```
var yourComponent = React.createClass(...
```

Is there is something similar like a React.createMixin(.. ? Or how would be the best way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is right, you just have a typo in the second version (should be `module.exports` instead of `module.export`):

```
var SetIntervalMixin = {

  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.intervals = [];
  },
  setInterval: function() {
    this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.intervals.map(clearInterval);
  }
};

module.exports = SetIntervalMixin;
```

Comment: Wow! You're right. Damn, what a mistake! My bad of using IntelliJ... I want to install Atom in RedHat (with the awesome react snippets - highlighting plugin) but I haven't been lucky so far. Anyway, thank you!